# Is there a difference between implicit and explicit conversion to float?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to compare the times of converting an int to float using explicit (i.e. `float(n)`) and implicit (i.e. `n*1.0` or `n/1.0`) and the times are almost identical.

Is there a reason to use the explicit way other than readability? Is there an actual difference?

---

```
import timeit
N = 100000

print timeit.timeit('(float(n) for n in range(1000))', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('(n*1.0 for n in range(1000))', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('(n/1.0 for n in range(1000))', number=N)
```

Output:

```
0.626700733696
0.634305166349
0.628865431089
```

Edit (Since most of the time was wasted on the list-comprehension):

*This measurement is without the list-comprehension bias*

```
import timeit
N = 100000

print timeit.timeit('float(1)', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('1*1.0', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('1/1.0', number=N)
```

Output

```
0.0105130892657
0.00183750462634   # ~6 times faster than explicit
0.00451134133505   # ~2 times faster than explicit
```

---

**Final compassion**

```
import timeit
N = 100000

print '='*40

print 'no variable look-up:'
explicit =  timeit.timeit('float(1)', number=N)
implicit_multiplication =  timeit.timeit('1*1.0', number=N)
implicit_division = timeit.timeit('1/1.0', number=N)
print 'explicit                                  ', explicit
print 'implicit multiplication                   ', implicit_multiplication
print 'implicit division                         ', implicit_division
print 'explicit to implicit multiplication ratio ', explicit / implicit_multiplication

print '='*40

print 'with variable look-up:'
explicit_with_look_up =   timeit.timeit('float(n)', number=N, setup = 'n=1')
implicit_multiplication_with_look_up =  timeit.timeit('n*1.0', number=N, setup = 'n=1')
implicit_division_with_look_up = timeit.timeit('n/1.0', number=N, setup = 'n=1')
print 'explicit                                  ', explicit_with_look_up
print 'implicit multiplication                   ', implicit_multiplication_with_look_up
print 'implicit division                         ', implicit_division_with_look_up
print 'explicit to implicit multiplication ratio ', explicit_with_look_up / implicit_multiplication_with_look_up


========================================
no variable look-up:
explicit                                   0.0117008736543
implicit multiplication                    0.00140456514782
implicit division                          0.0042846079441
explicit to implicit multiplication ratio  8.33060230236
========================================
with variable look-up:
explicit                                   0.0114346407568
implicit multiplication                    0.00372041813489
implicit division                          0.00400375711843
explicit to implicit multiplication ratio  3.07348269527
```

Comment: Readability isn't an actual difference?

Comment: It's opinion based... I actually think using `*1.0` is pretty obvious and neat

Comment: if you're golfing try `n*1.`

Comment: Well of course the implementation differs, e.g. try `dis.dis('float(n)')` or `dis.dis('n*1.0')`, but really don't reinvent `float()` for no good reason

Comment: also you're using python 2 and `range` generates a list. It biases your measurements

Comment: Using code to do stuff other than what it was designed for makes your code harder-to-maintain, imho. Also, not everything is about speed.

Comment: if you have `n+m`, `float(m+n)` is better than `m+n*1.0`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually the timing is bad because they never iterate over the generator

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't understand your comment about golfing :-(

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But it biases them all in the same way, right?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes, but in some cases it could dwarf the measurements.

Comment: @Chris_Rands oh the whole question is moot!!!! your code isn't doing anything, like _at all_ because of genexpr

Comment: @CIsForCookies `1.` is shorter than `1.0`

Comment: Oh, didn't see the `.`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed, but my actual timings with a list comp show `float()` is actually slower, perhaps becuause `float()` accepts a string too

Comment: by replacing your genexprs by actual loops I get a difference: calling `float` is slower than multiplying by 1.0 or dividing because of _name lookup_

Comment: @Chris_Rands don't create a listcomp for that: another bias. Use a standard loop `timeit.timeit('for n in range(1000): float(n)', number=N)`.

Comment: @CIsForCookies your question is interesting but your results are completely wrong: you're just timing the creation of the generator expression

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What's the other bias?

Comment: @Chris_Rands the creation of the list (append+realloc behind the scenes of the listcomp). Can feed the genexpr to a deque too,..

Comment: So what would be the bias-less way to measure this?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry I don't get it, why would the list comp bias one measurement compared to the other?

Comment: I'd like to answer the question, but I think you should do it, since everyone overlooked the genexpr thing in the first place. I mean; if the list comp creation is taking way more time than the float conversion, the variation between your measurements is reduced (dwarfed) (and there's also the range thing in python 2, why didn't OP use just `float(n)` to time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your measurements are wrong because you're passing a generator comprehension to `timeit`, so the inside isn't evaluated at all (credits to Chris for pointing that out BTW)

Why not just avoid a loop (because of other biases: `range` expanding as list in python 2, creating *list* comprehension or `for` loop control measured at the same time as your expression) by just doing:

```
import timeit
N = 1000000

print (timeit.timeit('float(n)', number=N,setup = "n=100"))
print (timeit.timeit('n*1.0', number=N,setup = "n=100"))
print (timeit.timeit('n/1.0', number=N,setup = "n=100"))
```

with that very simple benchmark which measures exactly what I want to measure, I get different results:

```
0.2391901001877792
0.1120344300726624
0.11477763911405542
```

So yes, calling `float` is much slower, because:

- function call
- name lookup (`float` could be redefined, it's not a keyword)
- argument testing (`n` could be a string)
- keyword argument testing (`float(x=1)`, thanks Chris again for that)

Other operations don't involve functions and are very fast, and probably optimized to do nothing when one of the operand is exactly `1.0`

EDIT: my theory about other code "dwarfing" the differences just bited me: I forgot that using `n` also involves name lookup so I changed my bench to remove all name lookups (except for the one with `float`):

```
print (timeit.timeit('float(2.0)', number=N))
print (timeit.timeit('2*1.0', number=N))
print (timeit.timeit('2/1.0', number=N))
print (timeit.timeit('2.0', number=N))
```

which gives me (on my poor i5 machine)

```
1.5391184875027701
0.196832246702201
0.19605593720477255
0.11489053989433051
```

now `float` really shows its slowness (I have added a simple float literal bench just to make sure that Python doesn't optimize a literal computation)

`float` construct is also more flexible, and can be useful as is: you could redefine it to do something slightly different, even if it's not recommended or just to make fun of your friends:

```
>>> float=lambda x : x+.000001
>>> float(1)
1.000001   (now is floating point math broken? :))
```

The rest of the time, multiplying by `1.` is faster.

Comment: Was just about to answer my updated measurements (no list comp)... When checking 100000 times it seems `1*1.0` is 1/10 times than `float(1)`

Comment: Nice summary +1, another reason `float()` may be slow (prior to Py 3.7) is it has to check for keyword argument, you can do `float(x=1)`